# Cannot push dotnet 3.0.100 app to Octopus from Azure DevOps

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, octopus-deploy, .net-core-3.0

I’m using the DevOps pipeline to push my dotnet build to an Octopus cloud instance.

It worked fine until I added the dotnet SDK 3 installer to the devops pipeline

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .net core 3.0.100'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: '3.0.100'
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```

The octopus part of my azure-pipelines.yml looks like this:

```
- task: OctoInstaller@4
  inputs:
    version: 'latest'

- task: OctopusPush@4
  inputs:
    OctoConnectedServiceName: 'XXX.octopus.app'
    Space: 'Spaces-1'
    Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.DefinitionName).$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    Replace: 'false'
```

I have tried every combination of OctoInstaller that I can think of including embedded and explicit version numbers. I keep getting this error message with @4.

```
Failed to push package. The Octo command line tool is too old to run this task. Please use version 6.10.0 or newer, or downgrade the task to version 3.*.
```

With OctoInstall@3 I get another error:

```
Failed to push package. The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet' failed with exit code 150
```

> Has anyone been able to use dotnet 3 with Octopus deploy? One option
>   might be to install the octo extension for dotnet but I’m not sure how
>   you would do that from the azure pipeline. Or to use a Windows build
>   instead of Ubuntu.

I also noticed an error in the build step.

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.0.0 at [/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

This means that octopus must be trying to use the dotnet 2 framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking carefully at the logs, I discovered that OctopusPush was failing because it depends on dotnet 2.0.0.  I added in a `yml` task to install that framework and now it pushes to octopus.

It might be neater to use the `dotnet octo` tool, as described by TrevorBrooks however I don't know how to install dotnet extensions in the DevOps Pipeline.

Comment: Very appreciate this solution shared here. You can accept this answer thus other SO users could refer to this solution directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dotnet octo` https://octopus.com/blog/octopus-and-netcore

The blog article explains in detail how to make this work.

For Azure Pipelines follow this article:  https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/build-servers/tfs-azure-devops/using-octopus-extension

Keep in mind

> The Azure DevOps extension tasks require Octo to be available on the
>   path when executing on a build agent and must have the .net core 2.0.0
>   runtime or newer installed. This may not always be possible such as
>   with the Azure DevOps hosted agents. In order to make this work, all
>   Octopus tasks will automatically attempt to download and use the
>   latest version of Octo tools unless they're available on the build
>   agent as specified above. If you would like to avoid any additional
>   downloads or to use a specific Octo version then you can by adding the
>   Octo Installer task to the start of your build definition. No attempt
>   will be made to download Octo if the capability is detected on your
>   build agent.

Comment: That's what I was talking about in my quote "install the octo extension..".  Do you know how to use this in the DevOps pipeline?  If so, please provide details.

Comment: Please use version 6.10.0 or newer, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I have tried various version including 6.10.0.  I have made my build work by adding a step to install dotnet 2.0.0 before the OctopusPush step.